# Storing files to S3 not working inside Celery worker

Tags: django, amazon-s3, celery, django-celery, python-django-storages

I am facing issues with storing files in S3 from django's celery task. I am doing following things

- Get data from DB
- Create the XLSX file with BytesIO
- Storing that file with `file.save` method of Django

code snippate

```
        try:
            excel_file = generate_xlsx_file(sheet_dfs)
        except Exception as e:
            logger.exception("Error while generating excel file")
            return

        # Save the report
        report = Report.objects.create()

        file_name = generate_file_name()

        # Save the file
        report.file.save(file_name, ContentFile(excel_file))
```

at the last line, celery worker just stops and don't process any other tasks as well.
Also this code works fine if I run it in django shell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was eventlet, I was running celery workers with eventlet and removing them solved the issue. I found the workaround for that in this answer:
[Celery with Eventlets fails when uploading to s3 (boto3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37418214/celery-with-eventlets-fails-when-uploading-to-s3-boto3)